# Discord Bot not shown logging in on Debug Terminal

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For reference, this is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import os
import logging
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\botlog\\bot.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
# bot intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guild_messages = True  #server messaging
intents.dm_messages = True  #dm
intents.message_content = True #for the message to have text inside
intents.presences = False
intents.typing = False #i do NOT know why is this is off, everyone wants it to be off


# redirect uri
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/'

# tokens etc
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'TOKEN_HERE'  
YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID = 'ID'  
YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'SECRET'  

# youtube Data API setup
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'
YOUTUBE_API_DEVELOPER_KEY = 'DEVKEY'  


BOT_BIO = "we're here for a reason"

# auth w youtube data api v3
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secrets.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'])
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=YOUTUBE_API_DEVELOPER_KEY)

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event #ts took me a bit
async def on_ready():
    logging.info(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return  # ignore msg sent by bot

    if message.content == "give gdyt":
        try:
            logging.info("Received 'give gdyt' command")
            search_response = youtube.search().list(
                q="Geometry Dash",
                type="video",
                order="relevance",
                part="id",
                maxResults=50
            ).execute()

            videos = search_response.get("items")
            if videos: 
                video = random.choice(videos)
                video_id = video["id"]["videoId"]
                youtube_link = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
                await message.channel.send(youtube_link)
                logging.info(f"Sent YouTube link: {youtube_link}")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("No results found.")
                logging.info("No YouTube results found.")
        except HttpError as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            logging.error(f"An error occurred while fetching YouTube data: {error_message}")
            await message.channel.send("An error occurred while fetching YouTube data. Please check the logs for details.")

            videos = search_response.get("items")
            if videos: 
                video = random.choice(videos)
                video_id = video["id"]["videoId"]
                youtube_link = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
                await message.channel.send(youtube_link)
                logging.info(f"Sent YouTube link: {youtube_link}")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("No results found.")
                logging.info("No YouTube results found.")
        except HttpError as e:
            error_message = str(e)
            logging.error(f"An error occurred while fetching YouTube data: {error_message}")
            await message.channel.send("An error occurred while fetching YouTube data. Please check the logs for details.")

#what makes it the bot fr (! command 1)
@bot.command(name="give", description="Get a random YouTube video based on your prompt")
async def give_youtube_video(ctx, youtube_prompt: str):
    try:
        youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey='devkey')

        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            q = youtube_prompt,
            type="video",
            part="id",
            maxResults=50
          ).execute()
        
        videos = search_response.get("items", [])
        if not videos:
            await ctx.send("L prompt, no videos.")
            return
        
        video = random.choice(videos)
        video_id = video["id"]["videoId"]
        video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"

        await ctx.send(f"Here's your video.")
        logging.info(f"YouTube video sent:", video_url)
    except HttpError as e:
        await ctx.send(f"There was an oopsie while fetching your video. Try again either now or later.")
        logging.error(f"An error occurred while fetching YouTube data.")

# run
bot.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Whenever I run this .py file, the debug terminal and/or logfile saved in another folder show no log of it logging in and before it usually said something such as `Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})`. The bot actually DOES appear online on Discord though.
**ALL STRINGS WITH IDS OR TOKENS ARE FILLED OUT IN THE ACTUAL CODE**

Probably because of this, the bot doesn't recognise commands, although only responds in dms when i prompt it the command "give gdyt", which was defined early in the code given above.

Comment: You can try testing whether it is reading your messages/commands by putting a print statement.

Comment: Do you have the proper intents enabled?

Comment: Yes, I assume, they're set at the very beginning.

Comment: Your bot can't process commands because you didn't add `await client.process_commands(<discord.Message object>)` in your `on_message` scope.
[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Comment: If the bot is only replying in dms then theres already smth wrong with the intents/permission. Make sure to also set those intents and the permission to send messages on the developer page.